# Check if every element of an array belongs to a set of values

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a boolean method which returns true if every element is 9, 1 or 6.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums1 = { 1, 9, 1, 6 };
    int[] nums2 = { 1, 9, 2, 6 };
    int[] nums3 = { 1 };

    System.out.println(isOnly916(nums1)); // should be true
    System.out.println(isOnly916(nums2)); // should be false
    System.out.println(isOnly916(nums3)); // should be true
}

public static boolean isOnly916(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 9 || arr[i] == 6||arr[i] == 1 ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The program returns true for all of them, but it should be returning false for second one.

Comment: What exactly is the question or the problem? Isn't the output not as you expected? The second array contains a `2` which is **not** `1`, `6` or `9`.

Comment: The program returns true for all of them while the second one is false.

Comment: Execute your code, on a piece of paper or using the debugger, instruction by instruction, and you'll see the flaw in your logic.

Comment: Your method returns true when it finds first valid element. It should do opposite, it should return `false` for first element which is not valid, and true after testing all elements.

Comment: Ah, I see now. The problem is minor, let me write an answer.

Comment: Are you iterating through all the elements?

Comment: Note that streams provide methods for that: `return IntStream.of(arr).allMatch(i -> i == 9 || i == 6 || i == 1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

Take a close look at your code:

```
public static boolean isOnly916(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 9 || arr[i] == 6 || arr[i] == 1 ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If the condition evaluates to `true` for an element you immediately decide that the result of the whole method is `true` instead of first checking **all** elements.

That means if you have an array like

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

your method will first take a look at the `1` for which the condition evaluates to `true`. Therefore the method executes

```
return true;
```

which ends the method and yields the final result `true` without first checking the `2` and the `3` which would yield `false`.

You need to take a look at **all elements** before you can decide that the array does not contain any invalid value.

---

### Solution

Therefore, consider this slightly modified code

```
public static boolean isOnly916(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // If value is invalid abort and return 'false'
        if (arr[i] != 9 && arr[i] != 6 && arr[i] != 1 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Checked all values, non was invalid
    return true;
}
```

with some kind of reversed logic.

Comment: Can't believe i couldn't see it myself) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with your method. It will return true the first encounter of a 1, 6, or 9. The method will return true based of the first index because every array starts with 1 (which returns true). You need to change your code to return false on the first encounter of a non 1, 6, or 9 and return true after the loop is finished. Your method should look something like this:

```
public boolean method(int [] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(!(arr[i] == 1 || arr[i] == 6 || arr[i] == 9))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums1 = { 1, 9, 1, 6 };
    int[] nums2 = { 1, 9, 2, 6 };
    int[] nums3 = { 1 };

    System.out.println(isOnly916(nums1)); // true
    System.out.println(isOnly916(nums2)); // false
    System.out.println(isOnly916(nums3)); // true
}

public static boolean isOnly916(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!(arr[i] == 6 || arr[i] == 9 || arr[i] == 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are just evaluating the first element of the given array and returning immediately if is 9,6 or 1.

You can change your condition to this:

```
public static boolean isOnly916(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != 9 && arr[i] != 6 && arr[i] != 1 ) { // if not 9, 6 or 1 then is false
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // if none of the array values is different from 9, 6 or 1 then the condition is true
}
```